# How to fix installation of gnome-settings-daemon-schemas in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04

I am trying to install NVIDIA on Ubuntu 16.04 like [this website](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/) says. After typing `apt-get install nvidia-current`, I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-current : Depends: nvidia-304 but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (>= 3.16) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: system-config-printer-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: unity-control-center-faces but it is not going to be installed
 unity-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (>= 3.16) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: systemd-services
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I type `apt-get -f install; apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon-schemas`, I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  castxml dff gccxml geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
  grilo-plugins-0.2 gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gtk2-engines gucharmap ibus
  im-config indicator-applet indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime
  indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-sound inguma
  libasn1-8-heimdal libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavdevice-ffmpeg56
  libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2
  libavutil-ffmpeg54 libbasicusageenvironment0 libbind9-90 libcamel-1.2-54
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcrypto++9v5 libdbus-1-dev libdns100 libfcitx-config4
  libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libgdict-1.0-9 libgeoclue0 libgeonames0
  libgif4 libgrilo-0.2-1 libgroupsock1 libgssapi3-heimdal libgucharmap-2-90-7
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libhdb9-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhunspell-1.3-0 libhx509-5-heimdal libical1a
  libido3-0.1-0 libilmbase6v5 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libkdc2-heimdal
  libkrb5-26-heimdal liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblivemedia23 libllvm3.7
  liblwres90 libntdb1 libopenexr6v5 libpanel-applet0 libpff1 libpgm-5.1-0
  libphonon4 libpoppler57 libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libpth20 libpython3.4-minimal
  libpython3.4-stdlib libqmi-glib1 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libregfi0
  libroken18-heimdal libsodium13 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3
  libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libtre5 libtrio2
  libunity-control-center1 libunity-settings-daemon1 liburl-dispatcher1
  libusageenvironment1 libusbmuxd2 libwind0-heimdal libx265-68 libzip2 libzmq3
  phonon phonon-backend-vlc python-apsw python-bluez python-characteristic
  python-ctypeslib python-dbus-dev python-distlib python-lzma python-lzo
  python-magic python-ntdb python-opengl python-pyqtgraph python-qt4-gl
  python-qt4-phonon python-tidylib python3.4 python3.4-minimal ratproxy
  ruby-rainbow ruby-rexec ruby2.2-dev ubuntu-system-service
  ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-control-center unity-settings-daemon
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 886 not upgraded.
41 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 184 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 403284 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.18.2-0ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (3.18.2-0ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.18.2-0ubuntu3_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/GConf/gsettings/gnome-settings-daemon.convert', which is also in package gnome-settings-daemon 3.20.1-2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.18.2-0ubuntu3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to run `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get autoremove`? And then try to install again?

Comment: `gnome-settings-daemon-schemas 3.20.1-2` - where did you get this package from? If Debian then mixing their packages with Ubuntu is going to cause issues. In that case you'll need to get rid of all Deban based packages & replace with the Ubuntu versions